# Rotated paraboloid/square root in pgf/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to redraw the following graphic in pgf/TikZ.

[image: graphic to redraw]

I struggle to draw the rotated paraboloid/the root function. I come this far:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,cap=round]
    \tikzstyle{axes}=[]
    \tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
    \colorlet{setcolor}{green!50!black}

    % help lines
    \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm] (-4.4,-4.4) grid (4.4,4.4);

    \draw (4.4,2) parabola bend(-1,0) (4.4,-2);

    \begin{scope}[style=axes]
        \draw[->] (-4.5,0) -- (4.5,0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,-4.5) -- (0,4.5);
        \draw[xshift=1 cm] (0pt,1pt) -- (0pt,-1pt) node[below,fill=white] {$1$};
        \draw[yshift=1 cm] (1pt,0pt) -- (-1pt,0pt) node[left,fill=white] {$1$};
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: solution so far]

I searched the documentation of pgf/TikZ, but am unable to find a solution.

---

Incorporating the solution of percusse, it is unfortunately being rendered as follows for me:

[image]

I am still looking into this. Maybe I need a newer version of pgf/TikZ or pgfplots.

---

Building on the solution of percusse, I just used a different filling method and got it working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[no markers,domain=-1:2,samples=500,xmin=-2,xmax=2,y post scale=0.8,grid=major]
      \addplot[black] {sqrt(x+1)};
      \addplot[black,fill=green!20!white,opacity=.6] {-sqrt(x+1)} |- (axis cs:-1,3);
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: My final solution]

Thank you!

Comment: It seems from the documentation that tikx only draws parabolas like $y=x^2$, not $x = y^2$. You can rotate it in place though with `\draw[rotate=-90] (-2,4.4) parabola bend(0,-1) (2,4.4);`

Comment: @mrothe: Is that the result you get from just compiling percusse's document, without any changes?

Comment: Mine renders fine

Comment: If you want to see the current version of your files, do what Gonzalo said [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59042/styling-an-article-document#comment124748_59063). Add `\listfiles` in your preamble, and search the log file for the version. For comparison, my version of `pgfplots` is `pgfplots.sty v1.5.1`.

Comment: @Jake, yes, sorry, that's from just compiling percusse's document.

Comment: @Alenanno: I have pgfplots v1.5. I am currently in the process of upgrading pgfplots.

Comment: If everything is updated to TikZ/PGF 2.10 and pgfplots 1.5.1, try also the suggestion given in this nice answer to modify the hatching which looks a little too crowded : [Custom fill patterns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54358/custom-and-built-in-tikz-fill-patterns)

Comment: Updating pgfplots to 1.5.1 does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For such purposes [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) is the ideal tool.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[no markers,domain=-1:2,samples=100,xmin=-2,xmax=2,y post scale=0.8,grid=major]
\addplot[black] {sqrt(x+1)};
\addplot[black,pattern color=red,pattern=north east lines] {-sqrt(x+1)} |- (axis cs:-1,3);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possibility

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0,1cm)},y={(1 cm,0)}] 
  \path [domain=-2:0,pattern color=red,
         pattern=north east lines,
         fill opacity=.5] (0,-1) -- (2,-1)--(2,3) -- plot  (\x,\x*\x-1) --cycle ;  
  \draw [red,domain=-2.5:2.5,samples=100, thick]  plot (\x,\x*\x-1) ;  
    \draw[thin,blue] (-2,0) -- (2,0) ;
  \draw[thin,blue] (0,-2) -- (0,4);  
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (1,0) ;
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]