# Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title

Tags: sectioning, fontsize, titlesec

I would like to increase the size of pretty much every headlines, so that it is more prominent than the normal text.

I read about the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/) package, but can't seem to find good example how to use the package.

Using Gonzalo Medina does in fact change the font size, however, it changes the default font as well.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 202, accepted):

### Standard classes

Here's an example using [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\subparagraph{Test section}

\end{document}
```

I used the simplified version of `\titleformat` (i.e., `\titleformat*`) since the only desired change was in size, but you can use the extended version if "bigger" changes are required. These are the default definitions for the standard classes (taken from the documentation):

```
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}[runin]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
```

so you can make bigger changes. The following image shows both the standard sizes and the ones obtained with the above modifications:

[image]

And here's an exampe using the [`sectsty`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{\LARGE}
\subsectionfont{\Large}
\subsubsectionfont{\large}
\paragraphfont{\large}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\subparagraph{Test section}

\end{document}
```

According to an edit to the original question, the OP wanted also a sans serif font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\subparagraph{Test section}

\end{document}
```

### KOMA classes

The above approaches are to be used mostly with the default document classes (`book`, `report`, `article`); if the document class used is one of the classes of the KOMA-Script bundle, then it's not advisable to use `titlesec` (See [Incompatibilities between KOMA-Script and titlesec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36299/3954)) but to use the features provided by the KOMA classes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\setkomafont{section}{\LARGE}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\Large}
\setkomafont{subsubsection}{\large}
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\large}
\setkomafont{subparagraph}{\large}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\subparagraph{Test section}

\end{document}
```

### memoir

For the `memoir` document class, the situation is analogous: is also not advisable to use `titlesec` (See [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954)) but to use the features provided by the class; in the case of the lower sectional units, the class provides the family of commands `\setXheadstyle`:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\setsecheadstyle{\LARGE\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\Large\bfseries}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries}
\setparaheadstyle{\large\bfseries}
\setsubparaheadstyle{\large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test section}
\subsubsection{Test section}
\paragraph{Test section}
\subparagraph{Test section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Works pretty good, except for the first modification. Because changing the size without further options, it changes to a different font.

Comment: @cherrung: How about just adding `\sffamily` to the list of corrections?

Comment: @cherrung as **Werner** said, simply add `\sffamily`, as I did in the last code of my updated answer.

Comment: @cherrung which document class are you using? The standard classes don't use a sans-serif font by default, so your last requirement makes me wonder if you are using some non-standard document class.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I use the scrartcl document class and I do like the sans-serif font.

Comment: @cherrung that is crucial information that you should have mentioned in your original question. KOMA-Script and titlesec are incompatible, so titlesec is not advisable here; I've provided an example on how to proceed with the KOMA classes in my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Sorry, didn't know it was crucial. Your previous version seemed to work though. Didn't even know that I was using KOMA classes...

Comment: On a related note: You're using `\setkomafont` for KOMA-script classes, which seems to point slightly towards what I'm looking for. Is there such thing as `\getkomafont` as well, or `\applykomafont` or the like? Because I'm making my own, more flexible header command.

Comment: What do all this sizes mean? How big are these sizes? For example, I am writing a paper and I am forced to comply to requirements like "14pt for Section's font size", "13pt for Subsection's font size", etc. Which of these I should use?

Answer (score 40):

## [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package options

For simple cases, you can use `\usepackage[<size>]{titlesec}`, where `<size>` is `big`, `medium`, `small`, or `tiny`.

### big

[image: big]

### medium

[image: medium]

### small

[image: small]

### tiny

[image: tiny]

### Example code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[medium]{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 21):

You can just modify the sectional commands with the appropriate font size. Here's a small example in the [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}}% from \Large
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}% from \large
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}% from \normalsize
\makeatother

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

For a different font, replace `\normalfont` with the appropriate definition. For example, using `\sffamily` will yield:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For completeness I'll give a ConTeXt solution also.

You can change the heading style using:

```
\setuphead[chapter,title]        [style=\tfd]
\setuphead[section,subject]      [style=\tfc]
\setuphead[subsection,subsubject][style=\tfb]
```

The font switch `\tf` equals the body fontsize, `\tfa` is 1.2 times `\tf`; `\tfb` is 1.2 times `\tfa` and so on. If you want sans serif headings, then use

```
\setuphead[chapter,title]        [style=\ssd]
\setuphead[section,subject]      [style=\ssc]
\setuphead[subsection,subsubject][style=\ssb]
```

Here also the same logic applies. `\ss` is sans serif at body fontsize; `\ssa` is 1.2 times `\ss`, `\ssb` is 1.2 times `\ssa`, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

```
\section{\huge{Human}}% this works fine
```

Comment: This works fine, but it isn't how you are supposed to use LaTeX. *Every* `\huge` or `\textbf` *after* the titlepage in our document is most likely false user input.

Comment: This will totally mess up the Table of Contents.

Comment: This is actually useful for my special use case, which was not a normal document anyways. I just wanted to change one place.

Comment: Useful for me as well, I wanted to change it for one section only, thanks.

Comment: A better simple solution is `\section[Human]{{\huge Human}}`...