# Smaller font size for appendix

Tags: fontsize

Because of the large amount of appendix pages, I am looking to change the font size of my appendix text. Google'ing returns lots of links on how to change the title of sections, but I am talking specifically about the content text (paragraphs), the title size can remain the same. Any ideas? I am using scrbook and the appendix package.

Comment: just use `\small` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that is it! Thank you. Is there any way to make the section and subsection text one 'size' smaller as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking to change some definition in your preamble?  If you just need it for a specific set of paragraphs, you can just use `\small` or a similar command like David suggests (with or without `{}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{sectsty}
\begin{document}
    \scriptsize This is text in script size.

    \tiny This is a different paragraph in {\small tiny size}, with a different sized section in the middle.
    \section{First Section}
    \sectionfont{\small}
    \section{Second Section}
\end{document}
```

[image: fontSizeExample]

For what the actual sizes are, have a look at this good answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24600/960).  I believe a section header is normally `\Large`, a subsection is normally `\large`, and a subsubsection is normally `\normalsize` so that might give you some perspective.  A command like `\sectionfont{\large}` or `\subsectionfont{\normalsize}` should change the size of all the applicable headers after it.

For a more in depth answer, check out [what Gonzalo had to say](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59727/960).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm basically looking to change the text size of one or multiple appendix files (they are all separate .tex files, so I don't mind putting '\small' at the start of these files). Also I would like to turn down the size of the section and subsections heading for these appendix files.

Comment: @WalterB i added section/subsection headings to my answer.  does that do what you wanted?