# titlesec error "undefined control sequence"

Tags: errors

I'm new to `titlesec` and LaTeX in general, trying to use it to achieve chapters in a `{book}` class that are medium-sized and on the same line, viz:

**Chapter 1: An Unlikely Event**

Here's a minimized example:

```
\documentclass[english,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\medium\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:}{1em}{}
\begin{document}

\chapter{An Unlikely Event}

\end{document}
```

The error that returns is:

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
<argument> \normalfont \medium 
                               \bfseries 
l.77 \chapter{An Unlikely Event}

--- HELP ---
TeX encountered an unknown command name. You probably misspelled the
name ...
```

I think this is probably a simple error on my part, but I'm too young to know what it is.

Comment: What is `\medium`? That is the problem.

Comment: since you're specifying fonts, and the next thing you ask for is `\bfseries`, you needn't specify "medium".  there is `\mdseries`, to which is equated `\mediumseries`, but no `\medium` -- but since it's redundant anyhow, you can just get rid of it.

Comment: `\medium` is a command that doesn't exist. Probably you meant `mdseries`.

Comment: I was trying to specify the size of the font, but I must have misunderstood the advice here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti

Comment: @StevenArntson -- then what you probably meant was `\normalsize`.

Comment: My solution is to do `medium` in this way: `\usepackage[medium]{titlesec}`. This seems to work. Thank you, -s

Comment: Yes, `\normalsize` works just the same---I will use that. Thank you! -s

Comment: `titlesec` [documentation](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) is a bit misleading as it lists `big medium small tiny` as valid format parameters. After more attentive reading, they appear to be format options for the package, not for the `\titleformat` command.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Would you like to provide an answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have used the command `\medium`, which doesn't exist.
what you probably meant is `\mdseries`, which is the default.

since you responded in a comment that what you really want to do is change
the size of the font, the command for that is `\normalsize`.