# Yet another section number question

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering

There are a number of numbering questions asked, but I haven't found one that fits this particular need:

```
1. First section

1.1 Second level

A. Third Level (italic)
B. Third Level (italic)

2. Another 1st-level section 

2.1 Another 2nd-level section

A. Third level    
B. Third Level
```

In short, `\subsubsection{}` and `\subsubsection*{}` are numbered as letters *A*, *B*, *C*, Both the label and the title itself should be italicized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't do things this way. Since your `\subsection*` levels are enumerated with letters, they are regular numbered sections, so you should use `\subsubsection`. (If you don't like typing `\subsubsection` you can change it to something else (e.g. `\let\lsection\subsubsection`)).  Then you can format everything simply with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}.}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 5):

Changing of the sectional fonts: [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764)

Adjusting the counter representation (somewhat relevant): [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsubsectionfont{\normalfont\itshape}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\Alph{subsubsection}}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Note that you may have problems using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) with non-unique counter representations.

For consistency, I've kept the sectional numbering *without* an ending period, since your `\subsection`s seem to be void of them. If needed, one can add a period. Either way, either add it to all, or remove it from all.