# Modifying what \part prints

Tags: sectioning, formatting, parts

I have uploaded a picture. I wrote

```
\part{Functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$}
```

and it printed what you see in the picture. However I just want it to be seen as

> I Functions from....

instead of writing Part I and skipping a line and then writing what I wrote. How can I modify that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice, from the point of ease-of-use (and also because that's the only thing visible in your post) is to use `\section` instead of `\part` with the following added to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
```

Here is a minimal example highlighting this output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{Functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

If you *must* use `\part`, here's a modification (patch, via [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) to the `\part`-related macro that sets it the way you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,etoolbox,lipsum}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@part}% <cmd>
  {\Large\bfseries\partname\nobreakspace\thepart\par\nobreak}% <search>
  {\huge\bfseries\thepart\quad}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: For adjustment of font sizes of `\section`, see [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764).

Comment: Hey, firstly thanks for replying. Secondly, I have tried what you have suggested, but I found it to be a bit problematic. When I use this code, whenever I use, \subsection or \subsubsection, then It prints the first number of the subsection (or the subsubsection) in roman and after the dot it prints regular numbers. For example If I do my first section and then my subsection: \section{First Section} \subsection{First subsection} it's printing I First section I.1 Subsection. So I think trying to modify \part instead of \section would be a better idea. But I am new at this,maybethereisanotherway

Comment: @CharlesCarmichael: I've added a patch for the appropriate macro to keep your usage of `\part`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that doesn't require changes to the sectional markup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\partname{\let\wild@card= }
\patchcmd\@part{\par\nobreak}{~\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd\@part{\Large}{\huge}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Functions from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m}$}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If you want to have more space in between the part number and the title you can change the second line of the patch to

```
\patchcmd\@part{\par\nobreak}{\hskip 1em}{}{}
```

with the desired amount of space. With '1em', as above, it looks like

[image: output_spaced]

Comment: Hey! Thanks for replying, It worked thanks! I don't want to be asking too much, but is there a way to make the number I , as big as the text?

Comment: @CharlesCarmichael Change to `\patchcmd\@part{\Large}{\huge}{}{}`.

Comment: Thank you @GonzaloMedina! My first version had `\huge` instead of `\LARGE`. Don't know why I changed that...^^