# Changing the heading, subheading and caption fonts

Tags: fonts, sectioning, captions, koma-script

I am using the `scrbook` class document and observed that the `heading`, `subheading` and `caption` fonts are different from the normal text font style.

Along-with the `scrbook` settings, I have `caption` package included, which helps me changing the `caption` font style only. But I'm not sure how can I change the `heading` and `subheading` fonts. Once I know the normal text style, I can copy the same style into `caption` package.

But how can I make them all (heading, subheading, caption and normal text) of same style, but of different sizes? However, the chapter `titlefont` style should remain the same.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,   % Schriftgröße
DIV=12,          % Seitenaufteilung
BCOR=5mm,        % Bindekorrektur
ngerman,         % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
Inhaltsverzeichnis ein
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[textfont={small,sf},labelfont={small,bf,sf},labelsep=endash,format=hang,justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec, graphicx, geometry, titlecaps}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
 %Chapter Headers%
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}   {\normalfont\Large\scshape\titlecap{\chaptertitlename}\enspace\scalebox{1.8}{\thechapter}\filright} {8ex}{\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\filleft}[{\titlerule[0.5pt]}]
 \titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\chapter{Fruits} 
\section{Apple}
The most of the fiber in apples is soluble fiber...
\begin{figure}[h!]
\caption{Apple Apple  Apple  Apple  }
\end{figure}
\subsection{Apple}
Most of the fiber in apples is soluble fiber...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setkomafont{<section>}{<font>}` to adjust the font to suit your needs. See [Change size of `section`, `subsection`, `subsubsection`, `paragraph` and `subparagraph` title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764).

In terms of the settings for [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption), remove the use of `sf` in the font selection:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,   % Schriftgröße
  DIV=12,          % Seitenaufteilung
  BCOR=5mm,        % Bindekorrektur
  ngerman,         % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
  Inhaltsverzeichnis ein
  ]{scrbook}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
  textfont={small},% Removed sf
  labelfont={small,bf},% Remove sf
  labelsep=endash,
  format=hang,
  justification=justified
}
\usepackage{titlesec, graphicx, titlecaps}

%Chapter Headers%
\titleformat{\chapter}
  [display]
  {}
  {\normalfont\Large\scshape\titlecap{\chaptertitlename}\enspace\scalebox{1.8}{\thechapter}\filright}
  {8ex}
  {\Huge\bfseries\sffamily\filleft}
  [{\titlerule[0.5pt]}]

\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\normalfont\large\bfseries}

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{30pt}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Fruits} 
\section{Apple}
The most of the fiber in apples is soluble fiber \ldots

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Apple Apple Apple Apple}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Apple}
Most of the fiber in apples is soluble fiber \ldots

\end{document}
```

<sub>[`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) is not suggested for use with KOMA-script.</sub>

Comment: Thanks. It works pretty well and I got the same text style for `caption` as that of normal text font. I tried the link you suggested and that works too. But I can only change the sizes, not the style; as I don't know the text style name. How can I find the name of the font I'm using? I can then use the  `\setkomafont{<section>}{<font>}` to set standard sizes. Lastly, if I remove `titlesec`, chapter headings changes and I don't get a `titlerule`. @Werner

Comment: @Yousaf: The name of the font is Computer Modern, and is most likely accessible via `\rmfamily`.

Comment: I tried `\newcommand*{\myfont}{\fontfamily{<cmr>}\selectfont}` and `\setkomafont{section}{\LARGE\cmrfamily}` commands but the section font remain the same, in both cases. @Werner

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\addtokomafont{disposition}{<font settings>}` or `\setkomafont{disposition}{<font settings>}` to modify or change the presettings for all sectioning levels. To change the size of single section level use `\addtokomafont{<section level>}{<size command>}`.

Note that it is not recommended to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. This package breaks some KOMA-Script features.

Here is a suggestion without `titlesec` and `titlecaps`. There is also no need to load package `caption`, if this package is only used to change the font of the captions and their labels.

```
\documentclass[
DIV=12,          % Seitenaufteilung
BCOR=5mm,        % Bindekorrektur
%ngerman,         % für Umlaute, Silbentrennung etc.
]{scrbook}[2015/10/03]

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% font presettings for all section levels
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\normalcolor\bfseries}

% formating the chapter titles
\KOMAoptions{chapterprefix}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
    beforeskip=-30pt,
    afterskip=20pt,
    innerskip=8ex,
    font=\Huge\bfseries\sffamily,
    prefixfont=\normalfont\Large\scshape
]{chapter}

\renewcommand*\raggedchapter{\raggedleft}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{\chapapp\enspace\scalebox{1.8}{\thechapter}}
\renewcommand*\chapterlineswithprefixformat[3]{%
    {\raggedright#2}#3
    \par\vspace*{\dimexpr-\parskip-5pt\relax}\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}%
}

% settings for captions and captionlabels
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small}
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\renewcommand*\captionformat{~--~}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Fruits} 
\section{Apple}
The most of the fiber in apples is soluble fiber \ldots

\begin{figure}[h]
  \caption{Apple Apple Apple Apple}
\end{figure}

\subsection{Apple}
Most of the fiber in apples is soluble fiber \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I tried this one and it works too. But it changed the text appearance as you can see the above mentioned picture from @Werner. Is there any way of getting the same text style, chapter headings and without even using a `titlesec` with `komma` class? @esdd

Comment: The section headings are using the same font family but different sizes and they are bold. The chapter heading uses the same font as in your MWE. If it should not use `\sffamily`, then remove this command from the chapter font settings. Note that in your MWE and my code package `fontenc` with option `T1` is loaded while the example of @Werner uses the default `OT1` encoding.