# How to insert the section name in the footer, without keeping the section name formatting?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, header-footer, sections-paragraphs

The code that I use for the header and footer in the article format is as follows:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\lhead{Project tile}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt} 
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{\leftmark}
```

The problem is that this also prints the formatting that I've put to the section name to make it stand out:

```
\section{\LARGE{\textbf{Introduction}}}
```

This just increases the size, and makes the section name bold. So how do I put the current section name in the footer, without the footer name also being big and bold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're following the wrong approach. You should avoid setting sectional formatting inside the title, since this would make its way into the marks (typically used in headers/footers) and also the ToC, which is not ideal.

Instead, use something like [`sectsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) to format your sectional fonts (see [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{sectsty,fancyhdr}
\sectionfont{\LARGE\bfseries}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{Project tile}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.0pt} 
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
\lfoot{\leftmark}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth>\z@
      \thesection\hskip 1em\relax
    \fi #1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Above I also updated the `\sectionmark` macro to avoid inserting `\MakeUppercase` as part of the default construction. You can remove that if necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a table of contents for the project that I'm doing, e.g. its just the section name and then the text. So how would I change the code above to do that. Also what does the code between \makeatletter and \makeaother do?

Comment: @UniStuffz: You can just remove `\tableofcontents`. I added it just to show that the formatting of the section title doesn't transfer into the ToC. The `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair allows the use of `@` inside macro names - something that is typically reserved for low-level programming. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd)

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you, usually I stay over at maths stack exchange, but thanks for answering my first question here.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a KOMA-class (scrartcl and so on) you can accomplish this without fancyhdr and with scrlayer-scrpage.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setkomafont{section}{<formatting>}% changes the formatting of headlines
\KOMAoptions{%
    headsepline=2pt,
    footsepline=1pt
}

\ihead{Project title}
\chead{}% if you leave this out the pagehead will contain the sectionnames, too
\ifoot{\headmark}% the i is for inner side of the page if you use twoside and left side if you use oneside
\cfoot{}% if you leave this out the pagenumber will be in the center, too
\ofoot{Page \pagemark}
\automark[section]{section}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

You might use \cfoot or \ofoot as an alternative to \ifoot. If you want those to be in the head just use \ihead, \chead or \ohead.

EDIT: Added the head- and footsepline.