# memoir: Change fontsize in section

Tags: sectioning, memoir

I would like to change one letter on small in my section

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[right=2.7cm,left=3.5cm, top=2.7cm, bottom=2.5cm,includehead]{geometry}

%section style
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}
                                                                     {\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\large\scshape}}%\bfseries}}
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}  
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname .\hspace{2.5mm}}

\begin{document}
\section{n-regular polygons}

\end{document}
```

This should generate N-REGULAR POLYGONS but I need n-REGULAR POLYGONS

Comment: **(1)** For me it's not clear what you are asking. **(2)** I think that your example code contains way too much stuff that is not needed at all to demonstrate your problem. **(3)** Please do not comment on this comment -- instead, update the question. **(4)** https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/ sounds like your problem (again, I do not understand fully what you are asking).

Comment: Which letter do you want to change? Can you please make a compilable MWE? If I try to run your code I get the following error message `
! You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I borrowed the definition of section style form [Rubens answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/376360/36296), as I cannot compile your MWE

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\newcommand*\lowercasecapitals[1]{\MakeLowercase{\large\scshape#1}}
\setsecheadstyle{\lowercasecapitals}

\begin{document}

\section{{\normalfont n}-regular polygons}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*\lowercasecapitals[1]{\MakeLowercase{\large\scshape#1}}
\setsecheadstyle{\lowercasecapitals}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Polygons}
\section{$n$-regular Polygons}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You should simply use `$...$` (which makes sense anyways). Moreover, you should restyle the section headings with `\setsecheadstyle` in `memoir`.

If you really need every first character in `\normalfont` you can automise like:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\latex@section\section
\renewcommand*\section[2][]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \latex@section{\textnormal#2}
  \else
    \latex@section[#1]{\textnormal#2}
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\lowercasecapitals[1]{\MakeLowercase{\large\scshape#1}}
\setsecheadstyle{\lowercasecapitals}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Polygons}
\section{n-regular Polygons}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Otherwise you should use the solution of @samcarter.

Comment: Nice, but "n" is math mode. I supose to change it, I should use \text{n}

Comment: @Blazej, added another solution (that does not use `$...$`)

Comment: I also think that the n should be italic. But that's not related to Latex :)