# How not to render section-level headers in bold?

Tags: sectioning, bold, article

I would like to turn off **bold** for section-level headers in LaTeX, but keep bold for subsection-level headers. Would this be possible? The document class I'm using is `article`. Thanks!

A MWE would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{This should not appear bold.}
\subsection{This should appear bold.}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: Would it maybe even be possible to do this only for **one** section, so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{This should not appear bold.}
\subsection{This should appear bold.}

\section{This should appear bold again.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. `\caption` has nothing to do with `\subsection`. Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) showing what you have tried and what your problem is.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59726/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be many ways to achieve your formatting objective. A particularly easy way is to exsecute

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\mdseries}
```

in the preamble.

Observe that these instructions do *not* change the default relative font sizes -- `\Large` for section-level headers, `\large` for subsection-level headers, etc. To change the font size of section-level headers to, say, `\large`, you'd just have to add `\large` to the argument of `\sectionfont`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty}    % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sectsty
\sectionfont{\mdseries}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{World}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up question: To limit the effect of `\sectionfont{\mdseries}` to just sectioning header, just issue the instruction `\sectionfont{\bfseries}` before the next `\section` directive gets executed.

Comment: Thank you. Just curious: Would it be possible to do this only for a single section, if desired? I edited my question again.

Comment: @Hermi: You can set it and then reset it, like [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZTL5MvmX).

Comment: @Hermi - Please see the addendum I just posted. (The solution is the same as the one given in Werner's comment.)