# How to make sections number look like book chapters

Tags: sectioning

Is it possible ot increase the size of the number of a section, while also slightly increasing the size of the section text. Now, when we are using the standard `\section` and `\subsection` within `\begin{document}` looks like the following:

[image]

What we would like is to have something look like the following, where the number of the section is much larger than the text, and the section text font is also increased in size. The subsection can stay as they already are.

[image]

**UPDATE**

The section are as we wanted them to be now, but it messed up or head of every page. We use `\pagestyle{fancy}` but it seems like it doesn't work well together with the `titlesec` library because if we remove the `\usepackage{titlesec}`, then my header is visible and contains *Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning*, but when adding `\usepackage{titlesec}`, the header just writes *0*. like that, which is very odd to us.

This is the main file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}

 \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=blue,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = black,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }

\title{Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning}
\author{Ahmad Josef Sahebzadeh\\}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}

\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}

\newcommand{\height}{6cm}

\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{1 cm}{4 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\pagestyle{fancy} %THIS DOESNT WORK WITH TITLESEC
\fancyhf{} %THIS DOESNT WORK WITH TITLESEC
\lhead{\thetitle} %THIS DOESNT WORK WITH TITLESEC

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\input{front}

\newpage

\input{introduction}

\end{document}
```

This is how it looks before adding \usepackage{titlesec}:

[image]

This is how it looks after adding \usepackage{titlesec}:

[image]

Comment: [sectioning - Change size of section, subsection, subsubsection, paragraph and subparagraph title - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59726/change-size-of-section-subsection-subsubsection-paragraph-and-subparagraph-ti) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `titlesec` package.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
\subsection{Motive}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** There is some compatibility issue between the `fancyhdr` and the `titlesec` package. So, to use the solution with `titlesec` package, I will recommend to use the `titleps` package which is an alternative to `fancyhdr` package. When combined with `titlesec` package, it should be loaded by using `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`.

To apply the changes in the header and the footer, the syntax of the `titleps` package is:

```
\sethead[heven-lefti][heven-centeri][heven-righti]
{hodd-lefti}{hodd-centeri}{hodd-righti}
```

You may go through [this page](http://www.texnia.com/titleps_fancyhdr.html) to find some examples with `titleps`.

For some reason, the `\thetitle` from the `\titling` package didn't work with the `\titlesec` package. So, I inserted the title of the article directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} % <------ changed
% \usepackage{titleps} % <------ changed
% \usepackage{fancyhdr} % <------ changed
\usepackage{vmargin}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}


 \hypersetup{
     colorlinks=true,
     linkcolor=blue,
     filecolor=blue,
     citecolor = black,      
     urlcolor=blue,
     }

\title{Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning}
\author{Ahmad Josef Sahebzadeh}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\renewcommand\cellgape{\Gape[4pt]}
\newcommand{\height}{6cm}

\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{1 cm}{4 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

% ---------------- changed -------------------
\settitlemarks{section,subsection}
\newpagestyle{myFancy}[\normalsize\bfseries]{
    \setheadrule{0.4pt}%
    \sethead[\ifthesection{Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning}{Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning}]%
    [][]%
            {\ifthesection{Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning}{Validation of Meteorological Data by Machine Learning}}%
            {}{}%
}


\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\LARGE}{\hspace{1ex}\Huge\thesection}{2ex}{}

\pagestyle{myFancy}
% ---------------- changed -------------------

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \section{Intro}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \newpage
    \lipsum[6-8]
    \section{Section 2}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** Consider reading [how to write an MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/219947). This will help you to get help quickly and effectively from this site.

Comment: Hi again, unfortunately it didn't work entirely as planned. It is in conflict with /pagestyle{fancy}, and adding the \usepackage{titlesec} messes up the header of each page. I have updated the question. It is my fault for not adding any code :)

Comment: @Buster3650 Please see the edited answer.