# How to change the formatting of chapter titles in the endnotes

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, endnotes

I'm using `pagenotes` in the `memoir` class for a book. This is all the code I'm using that I think is relevant:

```
\let\pagenote=\endnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\prenotetext{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2.3em}%
    \setlength\topsep{-\baselineskip}}
  \item}
\renewcommand*\postnotetext{\endlist\bigskip\medskip}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\idtextinnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*\notenuminnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter {\notesname}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\theenmark.\hspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand\notesname{Notes}

% Section title
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\uppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Then, at the end, I add:

```
\printpagenotes*
```

Which prints out nicely a list of numbered nodes, correctly formatted, divided by chapter. Now my question is, how do I change the formatting of the chapter title in the endnotes?

For example, right now it shows: CHAPTER 1 UNEMPLOYMENT TODAY

I would like it to be: CHAPTER 1 - UNEMPLOYMENT TODAY

Thanks!

Comment: `memoir` is a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\pagenotesubhead`, for numbered chapters, as

```
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\section*{#1 #2\ -\ #3}}
```

and `\pagenotesubheadstarred`, for unnumbered chapters, as

```
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubheadstarred}[3]{\section*{#3}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\pagenote=\endnote
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\prenotetext{%
  \list{}{%
    \setlength\leftmargin{2.3em}%
    \setlength\topsep{-\baselineskip}}
  \item}
\renewcommand*\postnotetext{\endlist\bigskip\medskip}
\makeatother

\renewcommand*\idtextinnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\renewcommand*\notenuminnotes[1]{#1.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\makepagenote

\renewcommand\enoteheading{\chapter {\notesname}%
  \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip}
\renewcommand\enoteformat{\noindent\theenmark.\hspace{5pt}}
\renewcommand\notesname{Notes}

% Section title
\setsecheadstyle{\large\uppercase}

\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubhead}[3]{\section*{#1 #2\ --\ #3}}
\renewcommand*{\pagenotesubheadstarred}[3]{\section*{#3}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Unemployment Today}
\pagenote[a]{test}
\chapter*{Unemployment Yesterday}
\pagenote[b]{test}

\printpagenotes*
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, it's not a good idea to use `titlesec` with `memoir` (see [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954)); `memoir` offers you build-in mechanisms to customize the sectional units formatting, so instead  of

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\large\uppercase}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

it's better to use

```
\setsecheadstyle{\large\uppercase}
```

as I did in my example code.