# Section title with subtitle

Tags: sectioning, formatting, memoir, titlesec

I'm using the `memoir` class, I would like to create a more fancy section title, but I don't have the necessary skills in LaTeX. I found many fancy section titles on this forum, but I don't know how to customize it to make it look the way I want it. Is it possible to modify the section title to look like this (I drew this myself in OmniGraffle):

[image]

However, with these options:

- Date and subtitle are optional, not all sections have them
- Date is not necessarily today, but some day in the past
- No section number is shown
- both section title and subtitle can be longer than single line

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one possibility, using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; before each `\section`, some  commands can be used: `\undefds` suppresses previous dates and subtitles; `\sectiondate{<text>}` assigns `<text>` as the date for the following `\section`, and `\sectionsubtitle{<text>}` assigns `<text>` as the subtitle for the following `\section`.

Since `titlesec` was used, somre restrictions apply (See [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954)). The code:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\nameundef[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname #1\endcsname\@undefined}
\newcommand\sectiondatefont{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
\newcommand\sectionsubtitlefont{\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE}
\newcommand\sectiondate[1]{\def\@sectiondate{#1}}
\newcommand\sectionsubtitle[1]{\def\@sectionsubtitle{#1}}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\huge\sffamily}{}{0em}
  {\colorbox{gray}{%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
      \vspace*{1ex}%
      \@ifundefined{@sectiondate}
        {}{{\sectiondatefont\@sectiondate}\\*}%
      \raggedright%
      \textcolor{white}{\huge\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}%
      \@ifundefined{@sectionsubtitle}
        {}{\\*{\sectionsubtitlefont\@sectionsubtitle}}%
      \vspace*{1ex}
      }%
    }%
  }
\newcommand\undefds{%
  \nameundef{@sectiondate}\nameundef{@sectionsubtitle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\sectiondate{March 15, 2013}
\sectionsubtitle{Test Subtitle}
\section{Test Section With a Title Spanning Two Lines}
\lipsum[4]

\undefds
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\undefds
\sectiondate{April 23, 2009}
\section{Another Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\undefds
\sectionsubtitle{Another Test Subtitle}
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

An image of the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your work, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

A possible improvement of Gonzalo's solution is using a key-value syntax:

```
\documentclass[article]{memoir}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{microtype}

\makeatletter
\define@key{mosquito}{date}{\def\mosquito@date{#1}}
\define@key{mosquito}{subtitle}{\def\mosquito@subtitle{#1}}
\newcommand\sectiondatefont{\normalfont\sffamily\itshape\bfseries\Large}
\newcommand\sectionsubtitlefont{\normalfont\sffamily\LARGE}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\sffamily}{}{0em}
  {\colorbox{gray}{%
    \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
      \vspace{.5ex}%
      \ifx\mosquito@date\@empty\else
        {\sectiondatefont\mosquito@date\endgraf}
      \fi
      \raggedright
      \textcolor{white}{\huge\textls[50]{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}\endgraf}
      \addvspace{.5ex}
      \ifx\mosquito@subtitle\@empty\else
        \endgraf{\sectionsubtitlefont\mosquito@subtitle\endgraf}
      \fi
      \addvspace{.5ex}
      }%
    }%
  }
\newcommand{\Section}[1][]{%
  \setkeys{mosquito}{date={},subtitle={},#1}%
  \section*}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Section[date={March 15, 2013},
  subtitle={Test Subtitle}]
  {Test Section With a Title Spanning Two Lines}
\lipsum[4]

\Section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\Section[date={April 23, 2009}]
  {Another Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\Section[subtitle={Another Test Subtitle}]
  {Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I added perhaps better control of the vertical spacing and also letterspaced the uppercase title. Unfortunately Computer Modern and Latin Modern fonts lack sans serif small caps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I love this forum already, I can't believe how fast I got great answers to my question.

Comment: This is a nice approach!

Comment: I applied your approach egreg and I love the way it looks in my document. However, I just noticed that it caused my TOC to disappear. I am using \usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref} to produce a PDF with TOC. Is there a way to fix this, or is this a hyperref issue? Thanks!

Comment: @m0squito You should use `\section` instead of `\section*` and add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` in the preamble, so that sections won't be numbered, but will go to the TOC nonetheless.