# Moving the chapter name in a titlesec frame?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters, titlesec, framed

I'm messing around with titlesec to make a frame with the chapter name in it. I can't figure out how to move the chapter name ("Chapter Foo" in the example).

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,book,openany,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{5em}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{15pt}
\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter Foo}
\lipsum
\lipsum[3-6]
\end{document}
```

This is what I have: [image]

This is what I want: [image]

I hope someone can help!

Comment: You should be aware that `titlesec` is not compatible with `memoir`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012/about-memoir-and-titlesec-incompatibility

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware of that. So I rebuild it with memoir only?

Comment: That should be better. There are many examples of `memoir` chapter styles: `texdoc MemoirChapStyles`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been mentioned in comments, [`titlesec and memoir`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954) are not fully compatible. You can use the built-in commands from `memoir` to easily define your style; a simple example (make the necessary adjustments according to your needs):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{Nordestgaard}{%
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[b][5cm][b]{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
  \raggedright\chaptitlefont\strut##1\par\smallskip%
  \end{minipage}}}
\setlength\afterchapskip{15pt}
\setlength\beforechapskip{-40pt}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{Nordestgaard}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]