# Niceframe problem - what to do?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

Building on the [code from Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123808/moving-the-chapter-name-in-a-titlesec-frame), I managed to make a nice chapterstyle with niceframe. The problem is that it sometimes renders poorly, at least in Acrobat Reader: 
[image]

Needles to say, I don't feel like sending this to a printer. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in [niceframe](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/niceframe)?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,book,openeven,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{niceframe}

%% This is the frame!
\makeatletter
\makechapterstyle{Nordestgaard2}{%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{cleared}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\rmfamily\HUGE\scshape}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
\vspace{-3em}
\begin{center}
\niceframe{%    
    \vspace{11em}
    \begin{center}
    {\chaptitlefont\strut##1}%
\end{center}
    \vspace{10em}
}
\end{center}
}}
\setlength\afterchapskip{15pt}
\setlength\beforechapskip{-15pt}
\makeatother
%% Thus ends the frame!

\begin{document}
\chapterstyle{Nordestgaard2}
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Everything is fine here using Lubuntu 11.10 with TeXlive 2011 and evince viewer.

Comment: Your image is missing...

Comment: @Ruben, try: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ansz.png

Comment: @Sigur, same here but I doubt that the print shop uses evince :)

Comment: I can't confirm this with any resolution possible with Adobe Reader 9.5 on Linux