# Using tikz to create section "bars" and "markers"

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning, formatting

Based upon this original post [include section name, as well as number in mdframed (theorem) header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170350/3235), I am using tikz to create a series of bars and markers (e.g. *Topic No*, *Summary*, *topic summary*), thus:

[image: Section header bars, including numbered option]

After innumerable hours of development and experimentation, I seemed to have reached a limit and am requesting help to complete the development of this macro. In particular, I need to better understand how to produce the lower two or three section bars to a particular specification.

1. I would like each of the three 'markers' to be in a REGULAR typeface, whilst the section header text itself remains emphasised strongly (i.e bold). I have partially achieved this effect for the second section bar. N.b. Document's default roman typeface is *Gill Sans Light* (see lipsum par.), whilst *Gill Sans (Regular)* is set as `mainfont`.
2. I would like the section header text to properly align left, i.e. as normal text and first two section headers.
3. I am aware that my definition of the new commands `\ssection` and `\tsection` is poor. Although they work, I suspect that I have not achieved this "appropriately"—though I'm not sure why.

---

If anyone can go further, I would ideally like to reverse the section bars with markers, by placing the markers on the left of the page, with section header text `flushright`. When I experimented with doing this directly, by inserting this command into the `\titleformat` command, it moved everything in a manner that was beyond me to develop usefully. Perhaps there are other ways of using tikz (styles?) that would be more efficient. But perhaps this should be the topic of a separate question…?

---

A MWE follows.

Note: it incorporates a couple of options (using toggle), which allow for an handbook option (fh), in which ALL section headers are unnumbered and a French translation option (fr), both of which are set to `false` in this example. I recognise that this is therefore not technically a *minimum* working example, but hope you are able to indulge me, since removing the toggles would require redefining integral elements of the macro.

With appreciation for assistance and advice given.

```
    \documentclass[a5paper, openany]{memoir}     

    \usepackage{fontspec}                           %   glurl.co/fs0
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gill Sans}
    \setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gill Sans Light}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.85in}{0.85in}{*}    

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
            \newtoggle{fr}
            \newtoggle{fh}  
            \togglefalse{fr}            %   english     
            \togglefalse{fh}        %   module handbook

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}        
            \definecolor    {bar}           {gray}{0.7}
            \definecolor    {marker}        {named}{black}

%   section bar headings defined, using tikz

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}         %   glurl.co/dFH
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\makeatletter
\let\currentsectiontitle\relax

\newcommand\sectionbar{
            \tikz[baseline,trim left=\trim,trim right=\trim] {
                \fill [\barfill] (2.25cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3cm,2.5ex);
                \node [ fill=\markerfill, anchor= base east, rounded rectangle,
                        minimum height=3.5ex] at 
                (13.8cm,{\vertical+\vadjust}) {\sectionmarker};
                \node [ fill=\barfill, anchor= base east, rounded rectangle,
                        minimum height=3.5ex] at 
                (\markerinset,\vertical) {};
                    }}          

        \def\sectionmarker{}
        \def\barfill{bar}
        \def\markerfill{bar}

        \def\trim{2.8cm}
        \def\vertical{0.1435}
        \def\vadjust{0}
        \def\markerinset{2.6cm}

\iftoggle{fh}{
            \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}      %   http://glurl.co/e7H
                {\large\bfseries}{\sectionbar}
                {0.1cm}{\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}    
                }{
            \iftoggle{fr}{      
        \def\@@topic{Th\`eme}       
                \def\@@summary{R\'esum\'e}
                \def\@@topicsummary{R\'esum\'e du Th\`eme}
                }{
                \def\@@topic{Topic}         
                \def\@@summary{Summary}
                \def\@@topicsummary{topic summary}
                 }

\newcommand\@sectionbar{
    \def\trim{3.5cm}
    \def\vadjust{-0.0875}
    \def\markerfill{marker}
    \sectionbar}

\newcommand\@topic{
    \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\space \@@topic \space \thesection}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\@summary{
        \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\@@summary}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\@topicsummary{
        \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\@@topicsummary}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\titlebar{\@ifstar\sectionbar\@topic}

\titleformat
    {\section}
    {\large}        %   \flushright, \raggedleft
    {\titlebar}
    {-0.68cm}
    {\bfseries\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}

\renewcommand*  {\thesection}   {\arabic{section}}

\newcommand {\osection}[1]  {\section*{\sectionbar#1}}
\newcommand {\ssection}[1]  {\section*{\@summary#1}}    
\newcommand {\tsection}[1]  {\section*{\@topicsummary#1}}
    }%end-toggle
\makeatother


    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Title}
    \label{title}

    \osection{Terms used in this study}
    \label{termsusedinthisstudy}

    \section{First section}
    \label{firstsection}

    \tsection{Topic summarised}
    \label{topicsummarised}

    \ssection{Study 1 Summarised}
    \label{study1summarised}

\lipsum[1]

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you know where can I get (a free version of) Gill Sans and Gill Sans Light in ttf format?

Comment: And also, what should happen with long titles spanning more than one line?

Comment: Apparently, from here: http://ufonts.com/fonts/gillsans.html

Comment: As for long titles, spanning more than a single line, I have eradicated them from my text, so I have no stipulation.

Comment: the light variant: http://ufonts.com/fonts/gillsans-light.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to achieve the desired result. Defining `trim right` with a separate token `trimright` was critical, even when the value was the same as `trim left` (i.e. `trim`). This caused the section header text in `ssection` and `tsection` to line up with that in `osection`. Then it was mainly a matter of defining the alternate values between `sectionbar` and `@sectionbar` respectively.

I incorporated `\textnormal` to lift the incumbent emphasis off the marker text. I would still like to change marker typeface to the medium weight font, but I trust this is simply a matter of further research, particularly since the font I want to use is already defined as the `setmainfont` (at present, `setromanfont`, the 'light' version of the typeface is used throughout).

Resulting macro:

```
    \documentclass[a5paper, openany]{memoir}     

    \usepackage{fontspec}                           %   glurl.co/fs0
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gill Sans}
    \setromanfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Gill Sans Light}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.85in}{0.85in}{*}    

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
            \newtoggle{fr}
            \newtoggle{fh}  
            \togglefalse{fr}        %   english     
            \togglefalse{fh}        %   module handbook

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}        
            \definecolor    {bar}           {gray}{0.7}
            \definecolor    {marker}        {named}{black}

%   section bar headings defined, using tikz

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}         %   glurl.co/dFH
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\makeatletter
\let\currentsectiontitle\relax

\newcommand\sectionbar{
            \tikz[baseline,trim left=\trim,trim right=\trimright] {
                \fill [\barfill] (2.25cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3cm,2.5ex);
                \node [fill=\markerfill, anchor= base east, rounded rectangle,
                        minimum height=3.5ex] at 
                (13.8cm,{\vertical+\vadjust}) {\sectionmarker};
                \node [fill=\barfill, anchor= base east, rounded rectangle,
                        minimum height=3.5ex] at 
                (\markerinset,\vertical) {};
                    }}          

        \def\sectionmarker{\null}
        \def\barfill{bar}
        \def\markerfill{bar}

        \def\trim{2.815cm}% inset unmarked bar
        \def\trimright{2.7cm}% inset header to match text
        \def\markerinset{2.6cm}
        \def\vertical{0.145}
        \def\vadjust{0}

\iftoggle{fh}{
            \titleformat{name=\section,numberless}  %   http://glurl.co/e7H
                {\large\bfseries}{\sectionbar}
                {0.1cm}{\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}    
                }{
            \iftoggle{fr}{      
        \def\@@topic{Th\`eme}       
                \def\@@summary{R\'esum\'e}
                \def\@@topicsummary{R\'esum\'e du Th\`eme}
                }{
                \def\@@topic{Topic}         
                \def\@@summary{Summary}
                \def\@@topicsummary{topic summary}
                 }

\newcommand\@sectionbar{
    \def\trim{3.6cm}% inset marked bars
        \def\trimright{2.75cm}% inset marked headers to match text
        \def\markerinset{2.58cm}
        \def\vertical{0.13}
    \def\vadjust{-0.0875}
    \def\markerfill{marker}
    \sectionbar}

\newcommand\@topic{
    \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\space \@@topic \space \thesection}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\@summary{
        \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\@@summary}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\@topicsummary{
        \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\@@topicsummary}}
            \@sectionbar}

\titleformat
    {\section}
    {\large\bfseries}       %   \flushright, \raggedleft
    {\textnormal\@topic}
    {-0.01cm}
    {\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\def\markerfont{\usefont{main}{m}}   % use 'main' font?

\newcommand{
        \osection}[1]{
                \section*{\sectionbar#1}}
\newcommand{
        \ssection}[1]{
                \section*{\textnormal\@summary#1}}  
\newcommand{
        \tsection}[1]{
                \section*{\textnormal\@topicsummary#1}}
    }%end-toggle
\makeatother


    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Title}
    \label{title}

    \section{First section}
    \label{firstsection}

    \osection{Terms used in this study}
    \label{termsusedinthisstudy}

    \tsection{Topic summarised}
    \label{topicsummarised}

    \ssection{Study 1 Summarised}
    \label{study1summarised}

\lipsum[1]

    \end{document}
```

Resulting pdf:

[image]