# Creating a section heading 'marker' in a medium font

Tags: fonts, sectioning

I have used tikz to create a system of section headers that provide different 'marker' options that highlight different kinds of section, thus:

[image]

I have defined a `markerfont`, Gill Sans, medium weight. Which is sampled in the `Normal section`. I have also used it in the marker, 'Topic 1'. I have been unable to find a way to use it for the other two markers, 'topic summary' and 'Summary', which seem to take their cue from the section header, which is emphasised bold.

**Is there a way to force these two markers to also take on the medium-weight marker font, without also taking on the bold characteristic?** I don't want to change the main light font variant used in the body of the text, but it is too lightweight to be used in the markers.

> (This question was originally incorporated in a larger question,
>   [Using tikz to create section “bars” and “markers”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232190/using-tikz-to-create-section-bars-and-markers), which I
>   managed to (largely) answer myself. I thought that the
>   seemingly minor element described above would be straightforward to
>   solve, but that has proven not to be so, hence my seeking guidance
>   on this aspect separately).

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a5paper, openany]{memoir}     

    \usepackage{fontspec}                           %   glurl.co/fs0
    \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
    \setmainfont{Gill Sans Light}
    \newfontfamily\gills{Gill Sans}
        \DeclareTextFontCommand{\markerfont}{\gills}

\setlrmarginsandblock{0.85in}{0.85in}{*}    

    \usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}        
            \definecolor    {bar}           {gray}{0.7}
            \definecolor    {marker}        {named}{black}

%   section bar headings defined, using tikz

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}         %   glurl.co/dFH
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\makeatletter
\let\currentsectiontitle\relax

\newcommand\sectionbar{
            \tikz[baseline,trim left=\trim,trim right=\trimright] {
                \fill [\barfill] (2.25cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3cm,2.5ex);
                \node [fill=\markerfill, anchor= base east, rounded rectangle,
                        minimum height=3.5ex] at 
                (13.8cm,{\vertical+\vadjust}) {\sectionmarker};
                \node [fill=\barfill, anchor= base east, rounded rectangle,
                        minimum height=3.5ex] at 
                (\markerinset,\vertical) {};
                    }}          

            \def\sectionmarker{\null}
            \def\barfill{bar}
            \def\markerfill{bar}

            \def\trim{2.815cm}% inset unmarked bar
            \def\trimright{2.7cm}% inset header to match text
            \def\markerinset{2.6cm}
            \def\vertical{0.145}
            \def\vadjust{0}

\newcommand\@sectionbar{
    \def\trim{3.6cm}% inset marked bars
            \def\trimright{2.75cm}% inset marked headers to match text
            \def\markerinset{2.58cm}
            \def\vertical{0.13}
    \def\vadjust{-0.0875}
    \def\markerfill{marker}
    \sectionbar}

\def\@@topic{Topic}         
\def\@@summary{Summary}
    \def\@@topicsummary{topic summary}

\newcommand\@topic{
    \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\space \@@topic \space \thesection}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\@summary{
        \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\@@summary}}
            \@sectionbar}

\newcommand\@topicsummary{
        \def\sectionmarker{\color{white}{\@@topicsummary}}
            \@sectionbar}

\titleformat
    {\section}
    {\large}        %   explore \flushright, \raggedleft
    {\markerfont\@topic}
    {-0.01cm}
    {\bfseries\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\newcommand{\osection}[1]{
                    \section*{\sectionbar#1}}
\newcommand{\ssection}[1]{
                    \section*{\@summary#1}}
\newcommand{\tsection}[1]{
                    \section*{\@topicsummary#1}}

\makeatother


    \begin{document}

    \chapter{Title}
    \label{title}

    \section{Normal section}
    \label{firstsection}

    \markerfont {this is marker font (Gills Sans) -- a medium weight font}

    \osection{Osection sample}
    \label{termsusedinthisstudy}

    \tsection{Tsection sample}
    \label{topicsummarised}

    \ssection{Ssection sample}
    \label{study1summarised}

\lipsum[1]

    \end{document}
```