# How to underline a section's title without using the sectsty package (memoir class)?

Tags: formatting, memoir, titlesec, sections-paragraphs

Can anyone tell me how to underline a section's title without using the `sectsty` package please? Indeed I am using the `memoir` class which prohibits this package.

Thank You.

Comment: If `titlesec` is not prohobited, it can do that. But be aware that typographically it's very bad practice: it dates back to typewriter times, when it was hard, if not impossible, to type in boldface or italic.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with `titlesec`, as one of the tags in the question suggests, but I wouldn't recommend this due to some know incompatibilities; see [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954), for example.

Here's one possibility using `memoir`'s methods only:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\underlinedhead[1]{\noindent\uline{#1}}
\setsecheadstyle{\underlinedhead}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}
\section{A test section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take into account that underlining is not considered a good typographical practice.

Comment: @Newbie You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer (if you consider it solved your problem) by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).