# maxsecnumdepth causes tikz titlebar to disappear

Tags: tikz-pgf, sectioning

I am using`tikz` package to produce a grey section-header bar (rounded at one end), thus:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}        %   set numbering level
\maxsecnumdepth{chapter}        %   default=section, 2

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}        %   levels < {n} not in TOC

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

                            %   create grey section header-bar
\let\currentsectiontitle\relax      

\newcommand\titlebar{%sections
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3.0cm] {
    \fill [black!15] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=black!15!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (2.8cm,0.13) {
%        \color{black}{\thesection}
            };
}}
\titleformat{\section}
    {\large\bfseries}
    {\titlebar}
    {0.1cm}
    {\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}   %   http://glurl.co/dFH
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

                            %   start MWE   

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*               %   table of contents
                            %   ------------------------    
\mainmatter                 %   document content

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\label{chapter1}

CHAPTER 1 intro

\section{Section 1}
\label{section1}

Section 1 intro

\chapter{Chapter 2}
\label{chapter2}

CHAPTER 2 intro

\section{Section 2}
\label{section2}

Section 2 intro

\end{document}
```

This originated from http://glurl.co/dFH (then reduced to eliminate redundant commands, by myself, using trial and error). I have remarked out the original command that placed section number in node at left end of section-header bar.

The problem I have is that when I set `\maxsecnumdepth` to {chapter}, which is what I want (so that sections are neither numbered in the text, nor in the TOC), the grey `tikz` section-header bar disappears—I suspect because the macro above depends upon the section being numbered.

Can anyone advise me on the most appropriate way to resolve this issue?

Please note: when running the MWE between the two settings (chapter / section) for `\maxscnumdepth` remember to compile twice to see the issue shift as described.

Thank you.

*My MWE produces the Chapter numbering twice. Not sure why.

Comment: Please complete your code in order to show us a full compilable document (which is, of course, as minimal as possible). Thanks.

Comment: most document classes define two formats for headings -- one for the starred version of the sectioning (no number) and one without star (numbered).  i suspect that `\secnumdepth` uses the format for the starred version, and you probably haven't provided a suitable format for that.

Comment: thanks @barbarabeeton; I wondered about something similar. Unfortunately, I don't know how to address it …

Comment: @johnbrc -- i'm not sufficiently familiar with the innards of `memoir` to be more specific, but i hope this can help point the way for someone else.

Comment: `titlesec` is not really compatible with `memoir`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you suppressed section numbering, you need the `numberless` key to `\titleformat`:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\setsecnumdepth{chapter}
\maxsecnumdepth{chapter}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\let\currentsectiontitle\relax      

\newcommand\titlebar{%sections
\tikz[baseline,trim left=3.1cm,trim right=3.0cm] {
    \fill [black!15] (2.5cm,-1ex) rectangle (\textwidth+3.1cm,2.5ex);
    \node [
        fill=black!15!white,
        anchor= base east,
        rounded rectangle,
        minimum height=3.5ex] at (2.8cm,0.13) {
%        \color{black}{\thesection}
            };
}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
    {\large\bfseries}
    {\titlebar}
    {0.1cm}
    {\gdef\currentsectiontitle{#1}#1}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}
Test text
\section{Test section}
Test text
\section{Another test section}
Test text

\end{document}
```

[image]

A page of the result;

By the way, I hope you've seen [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/3954). Be awere also that with your current settings, you'll get undesired results if the title spans more than one line.