# How to customise lower level heading titles when using the memoir class? (Or: is titlesec still incompatible with memoir?)

Tags: sectioning, memoir, titlesec

I'm using the `memoir` class I'm trying to customise the appearance of lower-level headings.  In one case, what I want to accomplish is very simple: adding a period at the end of a heading title (for example, to emulate what `amsart` does for `\subsection`).  I want the period to be added only to the displayed heading in the document, not in table of contents: that is a reason why I'm not willing to add the period manually at the end of each heading text.

I haven't found a way to do this using the functionality provided by the `memoir` class neither in the `memoir` guide nor searching the Internet.  In fact, I believe the latest `memoir` guide implicitly states this is not possible.  Section 6.6 reads:

> The lower level heads — sections down to subparagraphs — are also configurable, but there is nothing corresponding to chapter styles.
>   There are essentially three things that may be adjusted for these heads: (a) the vertical distance between the baseline of the text above the heading to the baseline of the title text, (b) the indentation of the heading from the left hand margin, and (c) the style (font) used for the heading title.

The most common (class-agnostic) way to deal with this kind of customizations in LaTeX is using the `titlesec` package but I've often read that `titlesec` is somewhat incompatible with `memoir`.  I went through the `memoir` guide, though, and I couldn't find an incompatibility statement.  On the contrary, the introduction to the eight edition states:

> The class also provides functions similar to those provided by the following packages, although the commands are different: `crop`, `fancyhdr`, `geometry`, `sidecap`, `subfigure`, `titlesec`. You can use these packages if you wish, or just use the capabilities of the memoir class.

Which is the right way to do what this kind of customisations when using `memoir`? Are `memoir` and `titlesec` now compatible? If it they are, is it safe to mix `memoir` heading customisations (e.g.: `\setsecheadstyle`, `\setaftersubsecskip`) with `titlesec`'s or should I stick with `titlesec` if I use it?

Comment: You have written *a lot* of text, so much that i didn't even read it. Can you provide a [minimal example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/) that puts the text into code?

Comment: @Johannes_B, the essence of my question is "Is there a `memoir`-specific way to customise the appearance of the text of a lower level heads?"  If I had working code for this one, I'd have answered my own question.  I put a lot of text to cite the relevant information I have, especially because a lot of people say that `titlesec` is "incompatible" with `memoir`, and `titlesec` seems to be the only package people cite when solving this problem.

Comment: Related: [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/2693).

Comment: Thanks @AlanMunn.  I had seen this one during my search, and it exemplifies why I'd rather not use a package that breaks the functionality of the `memoir` class.  However, I'm OK with it if that's the only side effect of using `titlesec` with `memoir` but I wasn't sure about it (hence, my question).  Thank you!

Comment: Do you har have a macro that adds a period if none us present? As far as I remember, the setsecheadstyle and friends allow you to specify as the last macro, a macro that takes one argument. For example `\MakeUppercase`. So you can do it that way. If you use titlesec then that package takes over and none of the memoir specific setting will be used (again as far as I know)

Comment: But if you are also using hyperref you will probably get in to all sorts of trouble

Comment: @daleif At least a simple version of an add punctuation macro will not work correctly: e.g. `\def\addpunc#1{#1.} \setsubsecheadstyle{\addpunc}` puts the dot on the next line.

Comment: Not at a computer, will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: If your title fits on one line, `\newcommand{\addpunc}[1]{\mbox{#1.}}` keeps the dot where it belongs. This seems to work OK with `\hyperref.`

Comment: @AlanMunn, my memory was wrong, it is the toc configurations you can do this with. `\section` etc is made using `\@startsection`, and memoirs version of that is more or less using the kernel components, so one may need to hack some kernel components.

Comment: Hmm, did not save in time, you will need to hack `\M@sect`

Comment: @AlanMunn, and this part explains why you get a line break in that test `#6{\@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec} \interlinepenalty \@M #9\@@par}`, here `#6` is the contents of the `\setsecheadstyle` (or what ever)

Comment: Thank you very much @daleif and sorry for the belated answer. I'm going to try your macro tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work. *Not tested with hyperref!*

Basically we dissect the `memoir` source code and use `etoolbox` to patch the macro. Note however, this does not include `\section*` and friends, that has to be done slightly differently, and omitted here.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% adapted from from amsthm
\def\MY@addpunct#1{%
  \relax\ifhmode
    \ifnum\spacefactor>\@m \else#1\fi
  \fi}

\patchcmd{\M@sect}{\@M#9\@@par}{\@M#9\MY@addpunct{.}\@@par}{
  \typeout{\string\M@sect\space patched (1)}
}{
  \typeout{\string\M@sect\space not patched (1)}
}
\patchcmd{\M@sect}{\@svsec #9}{\@svsec#9\MY@addpunct{.}}{
  \typeout{\string\M@sect\space patched (2)}
}{
  \typeout{\string\M@sect\space not patched (2)}
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{test}

\end{document}
```