# How to center section when using \titleformat{\section}?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I decided to use \usepackage[center]{titlesec} in order to center my sections, but I don't want them displaying the chapter/section numbering in the chapter/section headings so I applied the titleformat. But with this new macro, it erased the [center] command.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}
{\Large\bfseries}
{}
{0pt}
{\huge}

\titleformat{\section}
{\Large\bfseries} 
{}
{0pt}
{\large}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This shouldn't be centered}
\clearpage
\section{This should be centered}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{This should be centered}
Nothing to see here.
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It worked but generated a /par error on compilation.

Comment: See [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this ? :

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\centering\Large\bfseries} % format
  {}% label
  {0pt} % sep
  {\huge}  

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This shouldn't be centered}
\clearpage
\section{This should be centered}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{This should be centered}
Nothing to see here.
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I tried it and saw that \chapter{This shouldn't be centered} actually centered. Oh well but once I removed \centering it was all good!... But the numbers came back.

Comment: I found an answer elsewhere and used \setsecnumdepth{none}
\maxsecnumdepth{none} instead of \setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} and now it worked (as for removing the darn numbers).

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `titlesec` with `memoir`, see [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012)

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\centering\Large\bfseries}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\centering\large\bfseries}

\setsechook{\setsecnumformat{\csname the##1\endcsname\ }}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{This shouldn't be centered}
\section{This should be centered}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{This should be centered}
Nothing to see here.
\end{document}
```

[image]