# Add a period after section number with memoir class

Tags: sectioning, memoir, titlesec

I was using the `titlesec` command
    `\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}`
to add a period after the section number, but it isn't compatible with the `memoir` options :

```
\section[Section title in TOC][Heading section title]{Section title}
```

(problem already noted here [About memoir and titlesec incompatibility](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33012/about-memoir-and-titlesec-incompatibility))

My question is : how can I add this period after section number with memoir class (so, without titlesec) ?

MWE :

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[english,french]{babel}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents*
    \chapter[Chapter title in TOC][Heading chapter title]{Chapter title}
    \section[Section title in TOC][Heading section title]{Section title}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Where exactly should this number appear? References, TOC, Text?

Comment: In references it's not important, but in TOC and text yes !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is just for the formatting in the text, this is enough (it will also hit subsection and subsubsection

```
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
```

The default is the same (without the dot)

Comment: Thanks ! For the TOC, I used a `titletoc` code : 
`\titlecontents{section}[3.8em]{\addvspace{0em}}%
    {\contentslabel[{\thecontentslabel}.]{2.3em}}%
    {\hspace{-2.3em}}
    {\titlerule*[1em]{.}\contentspage}`

It seems to work fine with `memoir` for the moment. But maybe there's a more appropriate way to do it with the class macros.