# Two optional section arguments memoir with titlesec

Tags: memoir, titlesec, incompatibility

The section divisions in `memoir` are defined as:

```
\section[〈toc-title〉][〈head-title〉]{〈title〉}
```

When `titlesec` is used, however, I find I am unable to use both optional parameters:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\section[toc title][head title]{section title}
\end{document}
```

This is a [known](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33012/96227) incompatibility. How can I have different toc and header titles for sections when `titlesec` is used?

Comment: Why are you using `titlesec`?  A major 'point' of `memoir` is that you don't need to rely on as many extra packages because it has similar capabilities built into the class itself? Since you seem to like features that `memoir` has and `titlesec` lacks, this in itself seems a reason to pass on `titlesec` (which is a fine package in other respects).

Comment: (Please note that I asked why only because it may well be that the feature you think you need `titlesec` for can also be implemented via `memoir`'s own command set.)

Comment: The answer is: you can't. Use `memoir` facilities if you want to change the format of section titles.